# Installing Gephi 0.8.2-beta on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, java

I am trying to run gephi 0.8.2 on Ubuntu 15.04, but after a few seconds of loading, nothing happens.

On my terminal I run:

```
./gephi
```

and I receive the following message:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

It seems the same problem as on other versions of Ubuntu.

I have java-8-oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gephi doesn't works with Java 8, therefore install Java 7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

If you don't like Oracle Java 7 as your default Java, edit your `gephi.conf` in `gephi/etc`

```
nano gephi/etc/gephi.conf
```

and set `jdkhome`

```
jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/"
```

Comment: Don't thank me. Give me an upvote :)