# Install both Oracle Java 7 and 8?

Tags: java

As the title asks, I need both, both Oracle Java 7 and Oracle Java 8. I've installed Oracle 8 (through webupd8), but software I want to run (Gephi) will only work on 7. Please advise.

Comment: Why are you using Oracle's Java and not the OpenJDK? You can install OpenJDK 7 JRE with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Gephi 0.8.2-beta on Ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663379/installing-gephi-0-8-2-beta-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 1):

There should not be much of a problem installing multiple versions of the JDK. Only one will be first on the path but you can explicitly run the other as needed by just using its full path name. Depending on how you are running it you may have different settings associated with each program. For example in Netbeans each project has an associated JDK, so when I run some projects it runs with JDK 7 and others run with JDK 8. You could also embed different JDK dirs in startup scripts or .desktop files for each program.

Gephi can be run on a system where JDK 8 is first on the path with the command:

```
gephi --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/
```